# how to move to another view on mouse click

Tags: eclipse-rcp

In my RCP application I have two views,view1 contains a button 
This button shall switch me from view1 to view2 on mouse click
how can I make this switch?

Answer (score 1):

In the button click handler, you need to do something like this:

```
getSite().getWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().findView("ViewID").setFocus()
```